# Booting in safe mode or Repair if no keyboard synchronized

Tags: macos, imac, startup

We have a Yosemite iMac that won't boot, it reboots in the middle of the loading bar with the Apple logo.

Said iMac uses a Logitech bluetooth keyboard, and even if I press `Shift` or `Cmd + R` it won't boot in safe mode/recovery, which leads me to think the keyboard connect **after** the OS has booted.

Is there a way to enter recovery/safe mode if no keyboard is available? (we don't have an USB keyboard here)

Comment: Does the Logitech keyboard use the Apple built-in Bluetooth or a USB dongle? Supposedly Bluetooth is initialized after the startup chord (chime) but perhaps the Logitech keyboard requires drivers that aren't loaded until way after the boot process starts. I would suspect (guess) that Apple-branded wireless keyboards are initialized at startup.

Comment: @IconDaemon I was reading further and I now know Bluetooth is inited early enough to be able to enter in safe or recovery. But the fact that it doesn't work makes me think it either doesn't, or the Mac problem is bad enough so that I can't even enter recovery/safe mode.